# Adding attribute field to raster layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table

I am from Vietnam and I am still a student. I have to study more about ArcGIS.

How do I add an attribute field in this case?

My project is using Landsat 8 picture to establish a drought map. After calculating LST and VHI I reclassify it and my teacher tells me to add an attribute field to it. I don't know how to do it, I watch people do it in YouTube but when they open the attribute table it is very different.

How can I add an attribute field to my project?

I have to calculate the area of each region too.

How do I do that?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must not be in an edit session.  Click on the Table - Options button (farthest left button on the table toolbar) and select Add Field.

Comment: You are working with a raster dataset, not a vector dataset. This means that the attribute table is different -- it simply lists the number of cells which have each value.

Answer (score 2):

You are working with a raster dataset, not a vector dataset. (https://gisgeography.com/spatial-data-types-vector-raster/)

This means that the attribute table is different -- it simply lists the number of cells which have each value. You can convert the dataset using Raster to Polygon (Conversion).

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000008000000

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try This:
Follow the instructions via red boxes.
The editor must be off

[image]

Comment: You can add fields to an attribute table of a vector feature class even when the Editor is off. Also, the poster is working with a raster dataset (not vector) and won't be able to edit the attribute table.

Comment: @smiller, this answer will work. From the pictures posted from the OP the raster dataset is a reclassified raster. Raster outputs that are "Integer" allow for the attribute table to be edited exactly the same way as a Vector data type. Outputs from a viewshed, reclassify tool and the Int() functions as examples allow you add fields and attributes to the raster (numbers and text fields). The field calculator can also be used in these fields to further process data. The "float" datatypes cannot be edited.

Comment: @quyetlecong If you have the answer, please make sure you click the green tick to show the question is answered. It will help anyone who has a similar question or is looking for a similar result...thanks.